# C++ undefined symbol: NullPointerException error returned from a shared library

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with my code. A shared library is causing an undefined symbol error that I just cannot figure out. All of the files are in the correct locations and the shared library builds successfully but upon executing the program it returns the bellow message.

The error message:

```
libsp.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4Poco20NullPointerExceptionE
```

From what I can see the problem is the Poco headers I use. The headers I got from an outside source and they should all work, I believe the error is caused by how I call these headers, but I might be wrong.

Bellow is the only code that uses Poco in the libsp library. And the code of the 4 header files I use. I've checked and rechecked and cannot find any issues but am still getting the undefined symbol exception.

**File Spexec.cpp (libsp):**

```
#include "../poco/Poco/Base64Encoder.h"
#include "../poco/Poco/DigestEngine.h"
#include "../poco/Poco/MD5Engine.h"
#include "../poco/Poco/Path.h"

using namespace std;

stringstream s_base;
Poco::Base64Encoder encoder(s_base);

Poco::Path path(data.name);
data.path = data.name.substr(0, data.name.length() - path.getFileName().length());

    Poco::MD5Engine md5;
    stringstream ss;

    ss << data.created << data.name;
    md5.update(ss.str());
    data.name = Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex(md5.digest());
}
```

**File Base64Encoder.h:**

```
#ifndef Foundation_Base64Encoder_INCLUDED
#define Foundation_Base64Encoder_INCLUDED
#include "Foundation.h"
#include <ostream>

namespace Poco {

class Foundation_API Base64Encoder:, public std::ostream
{
public:
    Base64Encoder(std::ostream& ostr);
    ~Base64Encoder();

private:
    Base64Encoder(const Base64Encoder&);
    Base64Encoder& operator = (const Base64Encoder&);
};
} // namespace Poco

#endif // Foundation_Base64Encoder_INCLUDED
```

**File DigestEngine.h:**

```
#ifndef Foundation_DigestEngine_INCLUDED
#define Foundation_DigestEngine_INCLUDED
#include "Foundation.h"
#include <vector>

namespace Poco {

class Foundation_API DigestEngine
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Digest;

    DigestEngine();
    virtual ~DigestEngine();

    void update(const void* data, std::size_t length);
    void update(char data);
    void update(const std::string& data);
    virtual std::size_t digestLength() const = 0;
    virtual void reset() = 0;       
    virtual const Digest& digest() = 0;
    static std::string digestToHex(const Digest& bytes);
    static Digest digestFromHex(const std::string& digest);

presentation

protected:
    virtual void updateImpl(const void* data, std::size_t length) = 0;
private:
    DigestEngine(const DigestEngine&);
    DigestEngine& operator = (const DigestEngine&);
};
```

**File MD5Engine.h:**

```
#ifndef Foundation_MD5Engine_INCLUDED
#define Foundation_MD5Engine_INCLUDED
#include "Foundation.h"
#include "DigestEngine.h"

namespace Poco {

class Foundation_API MD5Engine: public DigestEngine
{
public:
    enum
    {
        BLOCK_SIZE  = 64,
        DIGEST_SIZE = 16
    };

    MD5Engine();
    ~MD5Engine();

    std::size_t digestLength() const;
    void reset();
    const DigestEngine::Digest& digest();

protected:
    void updateImpl(const void* data, std::size_t length);

private:
    static void transform(UInt32 state[4], const unsigned char block[64]);
    static void encode(unsigned char* output, const UInt32* input, std::size_t len);
    static void decode(UInt32* output, const unsigned char* input, std::size_t len);

    struct Context
    {
        UInt32 state[4];          // state (ABCD)
        UInt32 count[2];          // number of bits, modulo 2^64 (lsb first)
        unsigned char buffer[64]; // input buffer
    };
    Context _context;
    DigestEngine::Digest _digest;
    MD5Engine(const MD5Engine&);
    MD5Engine& operator = (const MD5Engine&);
};
}
```

**File Path.h:**

```
#ifndef Foundation_Path_INCLUDED
#define Foundation_Path_INCLUDED
#include "Foundation.h"
#include <vector>

namespace Poco {

class Foundation_API Path
{
public:
    enum Style
    {
        PATH_UNIX,    /// Unix-style path
        PATH_WINDOWS, /// Windows-style path
        PATH_VMS,     /// VMS-style path
        PATH_NATIVE,  /// The current platform's native style
        PATH_GUESS    /// Guess the style by examining the path
    };
    typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;
    Path();   
    Path(const char* path);
    Path(const std::string& path);

protected:
    void parseUnix(const std::string& path);
    void parseWindows(const std::string& path);
    void parseVMS(const std::string& path);
    void parseGuess(const std::string& path);
    std::string buildUnix() const;
    std::string buildWindows() const;
    std::string buildVMS() const;

private:
    std::string _node;
    std::string _device;
    std::string _name;
    std::string _version;
    StringVec   _dirs;
    bool        _absolute;
};
```

Comment: That is a linker error. You miss linking a Poco lib (libPocoFoundationd.so)

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer first of all, one question thought how do you know its this libPocoFoundationd.so library?  I mean do you see this from the code somewhere or..?

Comment: Its a guess from 'Foundation_API' and 'strings libPocoFoundationd.so | grep NullPointerException'

Comment: FYI the missing symbol is the typeinfo node for `Poco::NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hey there, linking the library in question changed the error message to:

undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

Now I don't want you guys to go through each of these linking errors with me so I'll try to run the grep commands to try and find the missing links in this.

Comment: Seems like it can't find the standard C++ library? (demangled, it's `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`)

Comment: Thats a strange one becaue I am using it -static-libstdc++